# Would a lightsaber cut through wood?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Usually we see lightsabers cutting through metals like butter, with a few notable exceptions. And we know it can cut through flesh while cauterizing the wound. But what about material with a different resistance to heat, like a wet log? Could a lightsaber cut a tree down with a slice or by just thrusting it into the wood, as trees don't really "melt"? What would the physics be of doing something like this?

Comment: The physics are best described as, "Yeah, that'd be AWESOME!"

Comment: At some point, everything melts.

Comment: ...wouldn't wood incinerate before melting?

Comment: Busy visualizing a woodchuck with a lightsaber.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I'm pretty sure that's true.  In theory you might get a sort of mini, continuous, steam explosion though.  At least, if the wood is wet enough.  In practice, I'm pretty sure there are examples of Luke cutting through live trees without this happening.

Comment: And how _much_ wood would a lightsaber light if a lightsaber could light wood?

Comment: Also no: lightsabers are ineffective against both wood, and the colour yellow.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In [Star Wars: The Force Awakens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens) we see both the antagonist Kylo Ren (using his funky red saber) and protagonist Rey (using Luke's lightsaber) cutting through trees with gay abandon. They seem to present no more impediment to the blade than a [vibro-knife](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100096/why-did-vibroblades-disappear-from-usage/100097#100097) through [butter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99977/do-they-have-butter-in-the-canon-star-wars-galaxy).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I’m sort of surprised this question got as many upvotes as it did, but this is a nice answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Adamant - The question is ok-ish. The previous answer is definitely lacking.

Comment: There should at least be a badge for first use of the phrase “gay abandon” on the site. Definitely feels like something I would have said at some point.

Comment: Also what a sci fi simile! "like a vibro-knife through butter".  Something you see every day really 

Answer (score 24):

Yes, several of the books describe Luke using his lightsaber to cut through jungles.

It also follows physics.  A wet log doesn't burn easily, but an oxy-Acetylene torch will go through it in no time.

Comment: Err, but a light saber isn't hot. You can't really compare it to a oxy-Acetylene torch.

Comment: Actually it takes quite some time to burn through wood with a torch. A laser on the other hand makes pretty quick work of it.

Comment: Lightsabers have to be hot if they cauterize as they slice...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim - Actually the heat up when the come in contact with matter.

Comment: In which books?

Comment: Yikes, it was some of the old Expanded Universe series, but I cannot remember which now.  It's been five years since I made this post!

Comment: @user606723 - I guess they just turn metal blast doors into glowing red room temperature putty as they cut through them Actually, that explains why no one has a problem using the glowing red putty as a handhold as they crawl through the opening cut by the light saber.