# Do they have butter in the (canon) Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, food

Prompted by a [recent comment in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23616081#23616081) from the greatly esteemed ♦TimPost, we know that they have a wide variety of foodstuff in the Star Wars Galaxy, but do we have any [canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars) in-universe confirmations that they have **butter**?

[image: butter sculpture of Yoda]

For reference, I'm aware that they have [blue milk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_milk) (that could theoretically be churned into butter) and that in the [SW:III Script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html), Obi Wan cuts through droids

> ***as if*** they were made of butter

---

Note also that the [Wookieepedia article on butter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Butter) doesn't appear to contain any canon sources, only outdated EU novels and comics.

Comment: Are we restricted to dairy butter, or are nut and seed butters fair game, too?  For the purposes of describing the ease of slicing through droids, nut butters work equally well.

Comment: @Praxis - Peanut butter would not. You cannot slice through it easily.

Comment: That's true, you cannot slice through UK-made peanut butter easily.

Comment: It's not a dupe because none of the linked articles in the alleged dupe question have a canon source. They're all from low-level EU novels and comic-books.

Comment: @Richard Which do you reckon is easier to slice through: peanut butter or droids?

Comment: @randal'thor - About the same, unless you've left it in the fridge overnight. In which case, the droids.

Comment: When I first voted to close, I hadn't noticed that the question asks for canonical sources.  The answer to the original question doesn't use canonical sources, so I have reversed my vote.

Comment: @Richard The dupe question is not asking for non-canon answers, though (it isn't tagged star-wars-legends). The fact that the answers only cite Legends sources doesn't mean the questions aren't duplicates.

Comment: I’m not sure whether I’m more surprised that someone asked whether butter exists in *Star Wars*, or that the question *is a duplicate*.

Comment: @pauld.waite - It's not a dupe though. Not only does the alleged dupe not ask the question, but none of the answers answer the question regarding canon sources.

Comment: @Richard: sweet, now there’s only one to be surprised about.

Comment: Butter Yoda was actually sculpted here in Toronto and displayed prominently at the Canadian National Exhibition: http://www.thestar.com/yourtoronto/cne/2009/08/27/butter_artists_keep_chillin_and_churnin.html

Comment: After some consideration, I've decided to reopen. The question asks about canon sources for a specific foodstuff, not just a general descriptor of foodstuff in the SW universe.

Comment: As I recall there was a notorious scene involving butter in the in-universe holofilm "Last Tango in Coruscant"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, they do.**

In the new canon novel [*Tarkin*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)), we find the following passage:

> Teller nodded. “***Burned through the pirates’ armor like a knife through
>   butter*** and blew the ship apart.” He turned to point to toggles on the
>   control console. “*Same system here.*”

This would seem to indicate that not only is butter found in the Star Wars galaxy but that it's a common enough substance that it's used as a metaphor for something easy to cut through.

Comment: Congratulations - this is post no. 100000 on SFF! :-D

Comment: Also a metaphorical reference in "Aftermath". Reference to consumable 'nut butter' in "Heir to the Jedi"

Comment: @NKCampbell - I wanted to avoid references by the omniscient narrator.

Comment: @Richard - That raises an interesting question - is the omniscient narrator in-universe? Good news re: Heir to the Jedi - the narrator is Luke.

Comment: @NKCampbell - It heavily depends on the book. As far as the novelisations are concerned, the narrator is omniscient but seems to be firmly embedded into the SW universe.

Comment: or that just our "Human translation" for their substance which most resembles our "butter" :P

Comment: @Skooba - Possibly, but that way lies madness.

Comment: I don't think that necessarily means that *butter* exists in their universe in the way that we know it to in ours. What if the butter Obi-Wan and Teller are referring to is a term for a particularly soft alien species that is known to be easily killed with bladed objects?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - There are mentions of blue milk and blue milk cheese. Where you get cheese you get butter.

Comment: I'm still not convinced