# What happened to all the Cortosis metal, armor and weapons?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, weapon, armor

In 4,000 BBY, Cortosis was incredibly common, with street thugs having full Cortosis armor and weapons, as seen in the *Knights of the Old Republic* series. However, by the time of the Clone Wars, Cortosis was so rare that there was a minor crisis whenever a small supply showed up. Do any EU works explain why the metal  became so rare and why all the weapons and armor disappeared in-between these two time periods?

Comment: My [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100195/31936) to another question explains that the Jedi had done their best to restrict mining of the ore because cortosis was effective against their lightsabers. This might be a duplicate because of that answer, but I'm not going to VTC yet until others weigh in.

Comment: @Null That doesn't really explain what happened to the pre-existing weapons and armor.

Comment: ...which is why I didn't VTC. But presumably the weapons were either lost or destroyed by the Jedi in the thousands of years between KOTOR and the Clone Wars.

Comment: Same thing as happened to Mithril :)

Comment: They started a cartel that artificially restricted the supply of cortosis being mined while simultaneously popularising the idea of using small amounts of cortosis for wedding and engagement rings...

Comment: @user867 Blood Cortosis?

Comment: Out-of-universe - world needed to be adjusted to game mechanics.

Comment: It suffered from "retcon rust", a rare condition that causes a metal to completely disappear within just a few books.

Comment: @RogueJedi May I dare ask, these street thugs you speak of, are they plot characters or common mobs in-game? The answer matters to canonicity.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Both.