# Are there any vibroswords or vibroblades in the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars

In the games such as *Knights of the Old Republic*, we see vibroblades/vibroswords but I can't remember seeing them anywhere in the movies. Did they appear in the movies? Were they spotted anywhere besides those games?

Comment: Don't have sources, but no.  They were mainly added into the games to have something lightsabers would actually have to fight against.  Something about a material that was more available in the old republic days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did vibroblades disappear from usage?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100096/why-did-vibroblades-disappear-from-usage)

Comment: @Radhil they were in the movies, according to the visual dictionary(as Forral has indicated)

Comment: @RogueJedi No, this is a different question than the one you've linked.  This one is asking if they've appeared elsewhere, that one asks "Why didn't the clones use them".

Comment: One of Snoke's guards uses a vibro weapon: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vibro-arbir_blade

Comment: I'm wondering if General Grievous' polearms and his droid guard polearms weren't vibro-axes of some kind.

Comment: I'm aware that the cortosis wasn't widely spread, yet, maybe the Star Wars films showed some vibroblades or mentioned them. This question isn't a duplicate - I'm not asking about using vibroblades against lightsabers.

Comment: For what it is worth, they apparently have shown up in the Clone Wars cartoon, The Mandalorian, and The Book Of Boba Fett. That said, they are TV shows, not movies.

Answer (score 15):

They are quite prevailant throughout Legends continuity starting in the Old Republic Era and continuing on from there through the Legacy Era, though they aren't all made with cortosis to make them able to block lightsabers.  In Return of the Jedi, Jabba the Hutt's skiff guards were armed with vibro-axes.

[image]

You can see an extensive list of appearances of vibro weapons on Wookieepedia [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vibroblade/Legends)

Their first mention (in publishing order) was in the novel Han Solo at Stars' End(1979).

> If it was me who'd checked out, would Doc have gone on a crying jag, Sess?  Would you?  I'm sorry, but life goes on, and if you lose sight of that, sweetheart, you're asking to be dealt out.
>
> Her mouth opened to reply, but she thought better of it and changed tack.  Her voice became as sharp as a vibroblade.  Very well.  Let's do business.

and their first actual appearance in a book was in Han Solo's Revenge(1979).

> The swoop-rider turned to the woman with an odd smile.  "I thought Zlarb sent you alone."  He then stared at Han.  "You have a fatal sense of timing, friend."  His hand dipped into the utility pouch on his belt.  When it came up again it held something that filled the air with an insistent hum.
>
> Han identified it as some sort of vibroblade, perhaps a butcher's tool or surgeon's instrument that the weapons scanner would register as an industrial implement.  It had been home-altered to include a large blade, and its haft was filled with a bulkier power pack.

Comment: Nice references! I thought Daley might have picked up the term from the Gamma World RPG, which came out in 1978, but the term "vibroblade" dates back to at least 1940 in stories by Robert A. Heinlein: http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=728